# Mocking react-beautiful-dnd with Jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, react-beautiful-dnd

The recommended approach to test components using `react-beautiful-dnd` [hasn't been defined yet](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/623). However, this is somewhat blocking me.

I can test my components using `react-beautiful-dnd` by wrapping them in `DragDropContext` as per [this recommendation](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/510):

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-testing-library'
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

import List from '../List'

describe('List', () => {

  it('renders', () => {
    const title = 'title'
    const {container, getByText} = render(
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={() => {}}>
        <List>
          <li>{title}</li>
        </List>
      </DragDropContext>
    )
    expect(container.firstChild).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(getByText(title)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

However, this seems like a sub-optimal approach. Instead, I would like to mock `react-beautiful-dnd`, but I can't figure out how to do that correctly.

Say, if my `List` component is wrapped in `Droppable` like so:

```
return (
  <Droppable droppableId='id'>
    {provided =>
      <ListContainer 
        ref={provided.innerRef}
        {...provided.droppableProps}
      >
        {children}
        {provided.placeholder}
      </ListContainer>
    }
  </Droppable>
)
```

how do I write the mock for a component using the `render prop` approach (which `Droppable` does)?

```
jest.mock('react-beautiful-dnd', () => ({
  Droppable: props => props.children()
}))
```

The above would work for a `higher-order component`. How do I change it to work for a component implementing the `render prop`?

Comment: I probably misunderstood something, but I don't see why your mock would not work. I think in the `hoc` you would return `props.children` from the mock, and with `render prop` it's `props.children()`

Comment: Hi @HermanStarikov. The thing is, the render prop should be a function that contains a `provided` argument, as that will then provide props to `children`. If I run the code as-is, I get an error: `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Answer (score 30):

I was able to mock `react-beautiful-dnd` for our library by implementing the following:

```
jest.mock('react-beautiful-dnd', () => ({
  Droppable: ({ children }) => children({
    draggableProps: {
      style: {},
    },
    innerRef: jest.fn(),
  }, {}),
  Draggable: ({ children }) => children({
    draggableProps: {
      style: {},
    },
    innerRef: jest.fn(),
  }, {}),
  DragDropContext: ({ children }) => children,
}));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm using Enzyme's `mount` function for integration tests!

Comment: It should probably be `droppableProps: {}` inside the `Droppable`.

Comment: My Jest tests were erroring with `Invariant failed:  provided.innerRef has not been provided with a HTMLElement.` and I was able to bypass the error with this mock.

Comment: Also, `Droppable`'s `children` function does take two arguments, so ending it with `}, {}),` is good. However, the `Draggable`'s `children` function takes 3 arguments, so it should end with `}, {}, {}),`.